# Azure - Dependency failed for Local File Systems after today emergency Maintenance

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We have a Oracle Linux 7.3 server VM that was running 4 Oracle Production databases that got restarted yesterday as part of the Planned Maintenance to solve the CPU vulnerability made public recently.

Although the status of the VM is currently showing as "RUNNING" we are unable to connect to it. Other database servers and application servers VM's that have also suffered the same maintenance did not experience the same issue and were available after maintenance got completed (so we think that we can exclude network connection issues).

Looking into the Boot diagnostics serial log of the affected VM we can see the following error message that we believe is preventing the correct startup of the VM and causing this issue:

[K[[1;31m TIME [0m] Timed out waiting for device dev-vg_stage-lv_stage.device.

[[1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for /u099/hm.

[[1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.

[[1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Relabel all filesystems, if necessary.

[[1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Mark the need to relabel after reboot.

[[1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Migrate local... structure to the new structure.

[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Timers.

[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network is Online.

```
     Mounting /u003/backup...
     Mounting /u002/backup...
     Mounting /u008/backup...
```

[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Sockets.

[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Emergency Shell.

```
     Starting Emergency Shell...
     Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
```

[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Emergency Mode.

[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Paths.

[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Login Prompts.

[[1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to mount /u003/backup.
See 'systemctl status u003-backup.mount' for details.

[[1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Remote File Systems.

[[1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to mount /u002/backup.
See 'systemctl status u002-backup.mount' for details.

[[1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to mount /u008/backup.
See 'systemctl status u008-backup.mount' for details.

[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Security Auditing Service...

[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Security Auditing Service.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...

[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...

[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Welcome to emerg[  125.511790] audit: type=1305 audit(1515074180.787:3): audit_pid=715 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=1

ency mode! After logging in, typGive root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue)

We've already opened a Service request with Azure support but no response until now. Do you have any recommendations on what procedure should we follow to recover this VM?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your root partition ran out of space and is unable to boot.
For fast recovery you can use Azure Backup or use AzCopy to make a copy of the VHD and then resize the OS root partition with PowerShell cmdlets or the Azure CLI. The VM needs to be in stopped (deallocated) state to run these commands

PowerShell:

```
    $rg = “YourResourceGroupName”  
    $vmName = “YourVMName”  
    $vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName         $rg -Name   $vmName  
    $vm.StorageProfile[0].OSDisk[0].DiskSizeGB = 127  # change the size as required
   Update-AzureRmVM –ResourceGroupName $rg -VM $vm
```

Azure CLI:

```
az vm update --resource-group YourResourceGroupName --name YourVMName --set storageProfile.osDisk.diskSizeGB=NewSize
```

After VM boots up see this post for more details on assigning the space to the boot partition.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/05/24/step-by-step-how-to-resize-a-linux-vm-os-disk-in-azure-arm/